# AWS Lambda upload by zip file not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, upload, zip

When I try to upload new version to a function in AWS Lambda, the option to upload a zip file is not allowed. (See the picture bellow)

[image]

It used to be able to choose the $latest version of a function and then to upload the zip file but now i cannot find it.

Any ideas what to do with this?

Comment: check [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtime-support-policy.html) if it is supported

Comment: And what should be supported? The new code isn't there yet. Do you mean that the old version of code is not supported and so it doesnt allow to update it?

Comment: I guess so. What is your runtime?

Comment: I'm sorry for a late response. Runtime is Node.js 10.x

Comment: I guess, thats not supported any more. You need migrate.

In phase 2, which starts at least 30 days after the start of phase 1, you can no longer create or update functions that use the runtime. To update a function, you need to migrate it to a supported runtime version. After you migrate the function to a supported runtime version, you cannot rollback the function to the previous runtime.

Comment: Ok, so there is no way, if the update went wrong and the function didnt work, to change it back? Not even some sort of backup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that the runtime of Node.js 10.x is no longer supported by AWS. It was needed to upgrade to Node.js14.x and after that, we could've update the version of our function.